# Why won't my program define the variable even after using a return statement?

Tags: python-3.x, return, nameerror

I am currently doing a challenge on hackerrank.com (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/finding-the-percentage/problem) about finding a percentage given a student's grade.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
over = len(scores)


def average_score():
    average = 0
    if query_name == _ in name:
        for scores in student_marks:
            for grade in scores:
                average = average + grade
            return average
        
average_score()
print(average / over)
```

I'm having a hard time making sense as to why the program won't recognize the variable (average) even after using a return statement.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(average / over)
NameError: name 'average' is not defined
```

Whenever I try to run the program, a NameError pops up.

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the result of the call to average_score.  Change it to this:

```
average = average_score()
```